# Service to temporarily queue UDP packets

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I have a service running on a linux box that receives a fairly constant stream of packets via UDP. The occasional loss or corruption of packets associated with using UDP is fine.

However, the service is under active development, and gets updated fairly often. Every time  updates get deployed to it, it has to be restarted and all of the packets that arrive durring the restart are presumably dropped. Also, every now and again a bug makes it into production that takes down the service goes down for a sustained period.

Is there a fairly simple service I can stick between my service and the incoming UDP packets, that will just pass through the packets to the service if it is available or, if the service is down for whatever reason, it'll queue the packets until the service comes back up and then pass them through?

Comment: You could build such an application, I don't know of one already. People usually just built a HA environment with failover for these sorts of situations.

Comment: If the packets are *important* and cannot be lost without impact to the service, consider adding data integrity checking in the application (to require acknowledgement of datagram receipt) or bringing in the big gun, TCP.

Comment: @ShaneMadden's right...you don't use critical data transfers using UDP. That's why you have TCP. Queuing UDP kind of defeats the purpose of UDP; you expect them to be lost and unreliable.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The application generating the packets is just shooting out notifications of events over UDP, and the receiving service is logging them. A lot like the way syslog works. We choose UDP because we didn't want the sending application to really care if the message arrives at its destination or not. It just shoots the message off and carries on. We can certainly tollerate missing events here and there due to lost packets. However, when the receiving service goes offline we basically have a lost period of time where no events get logged, which, while not fatal, is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and hacky solution would be to record the UDP stream in pcap format ([tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/)/[windump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) could do this) and replay it afterwards - for example using [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/).

It would require quite a bit of logic to include failure detection logic and automatic replays upon service restart, but if your service can handle duplicated messages using the hands-on approach should work well for planned outages.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd has a way of preserving sockets between daemon restarts (without losing data). Not sure it also works for UDP sockets, but I would expect so. Don't have more information, my Google fu is letting me down.